# IF-Then Error in R where seemingly no problem?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to use elements from a vector to conduct if-then statements, but for some reason, I keep running into the following error:

> "Error in if (xd[2] <= a) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

I am not sure why this keeps coming up, as the only thing that is different with that line of code seems to be that I am using xd[2] instead of xd[1]. I get my desired results with xd[1] but not xd[2]. The conditional seems to be met as well.

```
reset1 = {

a = 0.3 #lower bound of belief 

b = 0.9 #upper bound of belief 

A = 5 

w = c(1,2)

xd = c(1,2)

w[1] = 5   #cost of abatement/effort for Driver1

xd[1] = 0.3

w[2] = 3   #cost of abatement/effort for Driver2

xd[2] = 0.3



expfine1 = function(xd,A,a,b){if(xd[1]<=a){A} else if(a<xd[1] & xd[1]<b){(((b-xd[1])/(b-a))*A)} else if(xd[1]>b){0}}
expfine1(xd[1],A,a,b)

expcost1 = function(xd){proba1(xd[1])*expfine1(xd[1],A,a,b)}
expcost1(xd[1])

expfine2 = function(xd,A,a,b){if(xd[2]<=a){A} else if(a<xd[2] & xd[2]<b){(((b-xd[2])/(b-a))*A)} else if(xd[2]>b){0}}
expfine2(xd[2], A, a, b)
expcost2 = function(xd){proba2(xd[2])*expfine2(xd[2],A,a,b)}
expcost2(xd[2])
```

Comment: I am guessing here, but see if this helps. In the function definition of both expcost1 and expost2, you are passing a vector parameter but when you call it you are giving only a scaler value, you should try calling it by writing `expcost2(xd)` rather than `expcost2(xd[2])`, similarly int expcost1 as well.

Comment: This ended up working... I am still a little confused however as to why calling it as ```expcost1(xd[1])``` works but the counterpart for xd[2] does not.

Comment: Basically, your call to expcost1 work as there is no referece to its second index, ideally you are using scaler operation with an index, but with expcost2, your function uses [2] to access 2nd element, which suggest your input must be vector, there is no such condition in expcost1 hence it does work with or without square brackets.

Comment: Please, note that `expfine1()` and `expfine2()` are undefined for `xd == b`.  Perhaps, the condition in the second `if` clause should read `a<xd[1] & xd[1]<=b` (right closed intervall)?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Thank you all for your feedback and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `ifelse()` function, which is *vectorized*:

```
expfine1 <- function(xd,A,a,b) {
    ifelse(xd <= a, A,
        ifelse(a < xd & xd < b, A*(b-xd) / (b-a),
            ifelse(xd > b, 0, NA)))
}
expfine1(xd,A,a,b)
```

Comment: In the function definitions posted by the OP, `expfine1()` and `expfine2()` are undefined for `xd == b`. Your definition returns `NA` purposefully, I am not sure if this is intended by the OP. Perhaps, the condition in the second `ifelse` clause should read `a < xd & xd <= b` (right closed intervall)?

Answer (score 0):

From OP's code and [Tim's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60348740/3817004) I understand that the OP wants to create a function which interpolates linearly on the interval [a, b] and is constant outside of the interval.

For the sake of completeness, there is the `approxfun()` function in base R which returns "*a function performing the linear (or constant) interpolation*":

```
expfine <- approxfun(c(a, b), c(A, 0), rule = 2L)
```

This function can be call with a vector of `x` values:

```
expfine(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0))
```

> ```
> [1] 5.0000000 5.0000000 4.1666667 0.8333333 0.0000000 0.0000000
> ```

Note that there is a difference to OP's function definitions which are undefined for `x == b`. I guess that this happened inadvertently. I believe the intervals should be right closed consistently. Also note, that [Tim's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60348740/3817004) explicitely returns `NA` for `x == b`.

The function can be plotted

```
plot(expfine)
```

[image]